# How to bootstrap an Angular 2 application asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, angular

There is an [excellent article](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data) of how to bootstrap an angular1 application asynchronously. This enables us to fetch a json from the server before bootstrapping.

The main code is here:

```
(function() {
    var myApplication = angular.module("myApplication", []);

    fetchData().then(bootstrapApplication);

    function fetchData() {
        var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
        var $http = initInjector.get("$http");

        return $http.get("/path/to/data.json").then(function(response) {
            myApplication.constant("config", response.data);
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            // Handle error case
        });
    }

    function bootstrapApplication() {
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApplication"]);
        });
    }
}());
```

How do I achieve the same with Angular 2?

Comment: the same way . . .

Comment: so should i just look how to get the http client manually with the angular2 injector?

Comment: something like `new Injector([HTTP_PROVIDERS]).get(Http)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In fact, you need to create explicitly an injector outside the application itself to get an instance of `Http` to execute the request. Then the loaded config can be added in the providers when boostrapping the application.

Here is a sample:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide, Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
var http = injector.get(Http);

http.get('data.json').map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
      HTTP_PROVIDERS
      provide('config', { useValue: data })
    ]);
  });
```

Then you can have access to the configuration by dependency injection:

```
import {Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <div>
      Test
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('config') private config) {
    console.log(config);
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/kUG4Ee9dHx6TiJSa2WXK?p=preview.

Comment: First, thanks so much for this solution.  Second, would a promise be better in this situation, since you would probably only be expecting one result and you want a response in either case (success or failure)?  i.e. `http.get('data.json').toPromise()` Or does it really matter?

Comment: @dspies you're welcome! I understand your comment regarding promises but in the case of http only one event is fired and it completes after... So no need to transform to a promise ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to solve a similar problem and I needed not only to bootstrap the application asynchronously, but also to use an asynchronously initialised service in my application.
This is the solution, maybe it will be useful for someone:

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Service1,
{
    provide: Service2,
    useFactory: (s1: Service1) => new Service1(s2),
    deps: [Service1]
}]);

let s1: Service1 = injector.get(Service1);
let s2: Service2 = injector.get(Service2);

s2.initialize().then(() => {
bootstrap(Application, [
    ...dependencies,
    {
        provide: Service2,
        useValue: s2     // this ensures that the existing instance is used
    }
    // Service2 - this would create a new instance and the init would be lost
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Thierry Templier method also works with jQuery.
Here is my solution with angular 2.3.1 (file main.ts):

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
declare var $: any;

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

$.ajax({
    'url': './assets/config.json',
    'type': 'GET',
    'success': function(data) {
      platformBrowserDynamic(
        [
          {
            provide: 'appConfig',
            useValue: data
          }
        ]
      ).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    }
});
```