# Async initialization of Angular 2 service

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

I have an Angular 2 service that needs to do async work when it is initalized, and should not be usable before this initialization has been completed.

```js
@Injectable()
export class Api {
    private user;
    private storage;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.storage = LocalStorage;
        this.storage.get('user').then(json => {
            if (json !== "") {
                this.user = JSON.parse(json);
            }
        });        
    }

    // one of many methods
    public getSomethingFromServer() {
        // make a http request that depends on this.user
    }
}
```

As it currently stands, this service is initialized, and returned immediately to any component that uses it. That component then calls `getSomethingFromServer()` in its `ngOnInit`, but at that point Api.user is not initialized, and therefore the wrong request is sent.

The lifecycle hooks (`OnInit`, `OnActivate`, etc) does not work with services, only components and directives, so I cannot use those.

Storing the Promise from `get()` call would require all the different methods that depend on user to wait for it, causing a lot of code duplication.

What is the recommended way to do async initialization of services in Angular 2?

Comment: using `APP_INITIALIZER` may be an approach in some scenarios e.g. if you want the init to be called just once, see an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686406/how-to-load-lists-http-calls-on-startup-to-application-scope-in-angular-5
I realise your q is already answered but this may be useful for future reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After working with Thierry's answer for a bit, I discovered that it would only work once, but it did set me on the right path. I had to instead store the promise of the user, and create a new observable which is then `flatMap`-ed.

```
@Injectable()
export class Api {
  private userPromise: Promise<User>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.userPromise = LocalStorage.get('user').then(json => {
      if (json !== "") {
        return JSON.parse(json);
      }
      return null;
    });        
  }

  public getSomethingFromServer() {
      return Observable.fromPromise(this.userPromise).flatMap((user) => {
        return this.http.get(...).map(...);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This ensures that the `flatMap` function gets the user every time it is called, instead of just the first time, as in Thierry's answer.

Comment: What if user exist in LocalStorage ? Aren't you going to fetch it from http every time ?

Comment: @MadHollander the OP just wanted to wait for the bootstrap of the service before executing the http call - the http call isn't going to get the user, its just getting 'something from  server' which requires the user being resolved beforehand

Answer (score 5):

You could leverage an observable to do that with the `flatMap` operator. If the user isn't there, you could wait for it and then chain the target request.

Here is a sample:

```
@Injectable()
export class Api {
  private user;
  private storage;
  private userInitialized = new Subject();

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.storage = LocalStorage;
    this.storage.get('user').then(json => {
      if (json !== "") {
        this.user = JSON.parse(json);
        this.userInitialized.next(this.user);
      }
    });        
  }

  // one of many methods
  public getSomethingFromServer(): Observable<...> {
    // make a http request that depends on this.user
    if (this.user) {
      return this.http.get(...).map(...);
    } else {
      return this.userInitialized.flatMap((user) => {
        return this.http.get(...).map(...);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The thought has occured to me. However, I have many of these `getSomethingFromServer`, and this would require all of them to do this little dance. Is there a way to have something like an async factory pattern for this?

Comment: This approach could interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365134/angular2-bootstrap-with-data-from-ajax-calls/36370302#36370302 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180108/how-to-bootstrap-an-angular-2-application-asynchronously

Comment: The more I think about this, the better your solution sounds. I am having a go at implementing it, but I'm having a bit of trouble. Where is `Subject` from? Is it `Rx.Subject`? That doesn't seem to have an `emit` method. Generally, what imports do I need for this?

Comment: Yes you're right! There is a typo: it's `next` instead of `emit` (`emit` is when using the `EventEmitter` class). `Subject` is from rxjs and can be imported this way: `import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';` or `import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';`.