# how to load lists (http calls) on startup to application scope in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

I'm looking to load data on startup, for example countries in using a LocationsService.

**I'm implemented the current service:**

```
...

@Injectable()
export class LocationsService {

  public countries: Country[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getCountries() {
    if (this.countries.length == 0) {
        this.http.get<Country[]>(`${this.url}`)
        .subscribe(data => { this.countries = data; },
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log(this.countries)
        )
    };
    return this.countries;
  }

}
```

**I've tried to put the service inside the bootstrap:**

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent, LocationsService]
```

But it doesn't work (raise an error actually). I need this type of lists to be available from startup (load 1 time only). Thanks!

Comment: If you want to load one time then use this service in appModule

Comment: add a service to: providers: [ LocationsService ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use APP_INITIALIZER

first change your service instead of returning the data, return the Observable

```
@Injectable()
export class LocationsService {

  public countries: Country[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getCountries() {
    if (this.countries.length == 0) {
        return this.http.get<Country[]>(`${this.url}`);
    };
    return new Observable( c => {
      c.next(this.countries);
      c.complete();
   });
  }

}
```

create a service for setup

```
@Injectable()
export class SetupLocations {



  constructor(private loc: LocationsService ) {
  }

  public initliaze(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        this.loc.getCountries().subscribe((response) =>{

         //Do whatever you want here.

         //always call resolve method, because it will freeze your app.   
         resolve(true);

       }, (err) =>{});
     })
  }

}
```

next initialize it in your main module

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from "@angular/core";



//create a function outside in the class module
export function SetupApp(setup: SetupLocations) {
    return () => setup.initliaze();
}



 @NgModule({
   providers: [
     SetupLocations,
     { 
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: SetupApp,
        deps: [SetupLocations],
        multi: true
     }]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I've tried the propose code and I got error for the seFactory: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'seFactory' does not exist in type 'Provider'.

Comment: change it to 'useFactory' sorry, misspelled

Comment: the app doesn't boot up?

Comment: compiled and ng serve is successful but nothing being displayed, blank white screen, something in the code you provided  for the app.module.ts is broken.

Comment: Sorry, it's working now! I had an issue in the service itself,
just one more question please: 
where should I define he properties which are supposed to be in application scope: 
inside SetupLocations do: public countries: Country[]; ?
and add getter method to the same ?

Comment: No need looks good to me, if you want to access the  countries data you could just say (Assume location: LocationsService ) -> this.location.getCountries().subscribe((response) =>{  //do whatever your want  });

Comment: And one more thing initialize your countries to empty array, do that in the constructor. this.countries = [];

Comment: ok, so the countries[] will be only in the LocationService, got you.

Comment: What happens in HTTP call in APP_INITIALIZER fails? I would like to display an error like "unable to init the app"