# How to make a request before angular 4 application bootstrap

Tags: angular

We need to ensure in Angular 4 application that on bootstrap of AppModule (root module) there will be information about loggedin user already available. How to achieve it?

I was trying to implement this solution:

[How to call an rest api while bootstrapping angular 2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619443/how-to-call-an-rest-api-while-bootstrapping-angular-2-app)

but the problem is - application just send a request while bootstraping. I need to have data on initialization, that's why I'd like to start bootstraping on promise success.

I also tried this one:

[How to bootstrap an Angular 2 application asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180108/how-to-bootstrap-an-angular-2-application-asynchronously/36183631#36183631)

But it seems out-of-date.

Injector.resolveAndCreate() method not exists in Angular 4 version and HTTP_PROVIDERS cannot be imported. Any other ideas / solutions?

Comment: You can use the [Resolve Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) for your root component

Comment: What do you mean? What way?

Comment: I'm asking what way, because I don't have a routing to AppComponent, where I'd like to have that data (before any route is activated).